# How to Split Select Query result

Tags: sql-server

I have a select query,that select all data from ‘policy’ table based an ‘agentid’.

```
Select * from policy where agentid = ‘232’
```

This ‘policy’ table has expirydate field (date range 31/12/2012 to 01/02/2013) this show the date of policy expiry. Each date contain many policies

Now I want to divide the output in to 3 distinct lists based on expiry date. Each list need to contain unique record.ie.if the record exists in list 1 need to be ignore in the other 2 list

For ex: I need the output be

```
Query one – list one 
FOI1334816 01/03/2012 Mr sharon peckham
TOI3454563 07/12/2012 Mr elizabeth goddard
RTY8383831 12/06/2012 Mr Natalie Door

Query 2 – list 2
BOC1334846 01/03/2012 Mr Natalie Nunes
LOI7853532 07/12/2012 Mr Door D
ASE4472894 12/06/2012 Mr Michelle Hill

Query 3 - list 3
CIL1334894 01/03/2012 Mr Maxine Skelton
BNM7488480 07/12/2012 Mr peckham Nunes
DER5357323 12/06/2012 Mr Graham Lee
```

How to alter the select query.I have no issue in executing 3 separate query to get this result. Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
SG

Comment: What specifies what goes into list 1? list 2? list 3?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I fully understand your question. However:

If you are running SQLServer as your tag suggests, you can just write the 3 queries (with their corresponded WHERE clauses) separately in an empty tab and press F5. It will run the three of them and you'll have them separated in the results window.

For example:

```
Select * from policy where agentid = ‘232’
Where expiryDate < getdate()

Select * from policy where agentid = ‘232’
Where expiryDate > getdate()
```

There you'll have 2  **separated** query results. If you want to have 3 just type three. If the Where clauses exclude the same column with a between or a < or >, 99% of the times you won't have a same record in more than 1 query.

Hope this helps...